# Fisheye distortion while raycasting

Tags: java, swing, awt, raycasting

I've made a raycaster in java, and I'm getting the fisheye distortion that I've gotten before in javascript, however, I was able to correct it then but using the same method, (correctedDistance = distance * cos(ray angle)), now it doesn't seem to be working, here is a screenshot [image: Java raycaster]

I'm also getting a weird problem with lines in between the walls, but I think I know what is causing that and that is not the main focus of this post.

```
package renderer.elements.rays;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import renderer.display.Display;
import renderer.elements.player.Player;
import renderer.utils.conversion.DegRad;
import renderer.utils.scale.Map;

public class Ray {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double x2;
    private double y2;
    private double angle;
    double ra;
    
    public Ray(double x,double y, double x2, double y2, double angle) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
        this.angle = angle;
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.drawLine((int)this.x,(int)this.y,(int)this.x2,(int)this.y2);
    }

    public void draw3d(Graphics g) {
        double rayW = Display.WIDTH/(CastRays.FOV/CastRays.interval);
        int rayIndex = CastRays.rays.indexOf(this);
        
        double d = Math.sqrt( ((x2 - x) * (x2 - x)) + ((y2 - y) * (y2 - y)) );
        
        if(angle > Player.angle) {
            double ra = (Player.angle + DegRad.degToRad(90)) - angle;
        }else {
            double ra = (Player.angle - DegRad.degToRad(90)) - angle;
        }
        
        double cd = d * Math.cos(ra);
        
        double xWall = x2 - (Math.round((x2)/Display.tileSize)*Display.tileSize);
        double yWall = y2 - (Math.round((y2)/Display.tileSize)*Display.tileSize);
        
        if(Math.abs(xWall) < Math.abs(yWall)) {
            g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));
        }else {
            g.setColor(new Color(155,0,0));
        }
        
        double rh = Map.map(cd, 0, 200, 200, 10);
        g.fillRect((int) (rayIndex * rayW),(int)(500 - rh/2 ), (int) rayW + 1, (int)rh );

        g.setColor(new Color(44, 137, 184));
        g.fillRect((int) (rayIndex * rayW),0, (int) rayW + 1,(int)(500 - rh/2 ));
        
        g.setColor(new Color(44, 184, 63));
        g.fillRect((int) (rayIndex * rayW),(int)(500 - rh/2 ) + (int)rh, (int) rayW + 1,Display.HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

This is my first project in java, so my code might be unorganized or bad.
You can also view the [GitHub Page](https://github.com/rbgrube/raycaster)

Comment: It's highly unlikely anybody is going to download and run some random jar file off the Internet. [edit] and add the code to the question.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).